# How to create Message Sequence Charts(MSC) in Python?

Tags: sequence-diagram

I was looking for a way to create MSC via program and not using any tool. I came across this : http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/. The language syntax looks pretty straight forward but I am unable to figure out how to execute in on Windows platform.

Also, as I would be parsing a text file using python and then generate these charts automatically, is there any easy way to MSC in Python ?

Comment: MSC is not UML.

Comment: That actually means, you are asking an OT question for two reasons.

Comment: (1) For mscgen there is a Cygwin package - which'd enable you to run it under ms windows - there's a link on the mscgen homepage. (2) writing an interpreter and rendering engine for MSC's is fun & doable in any language - but not trivial (I did this in javascript) (3) if you want to use/ try mscgen in your browser (even internet explorer): https://mscgen.js.org (open source)

Comment: See http://blockdiag.com/en/seqdiag/index.html